# user.isAuthorized always returns false no matter of mongodb user role entries with vertx JWT auth

Tags: mongodb, authorization, vert.x

Stack:

- Vert.x JWT auth
- Vert.x Mongo auth

**User collection** (used in the authentication process):

`{"username":"admin","roles":["myasd_manager"],"permissions":[],...}`

**Problem:**

`isAuthorized("role:myasd_manager")` returns `false` *(true expected)*.

**Method calls:**

```
String requiredRole = MongoAuth.ROLE_PREFIX + "myasd_manager";
routingContext.user().isAuthorized(requiredRole, res -> {res.result()});
```

My JWT auth provider is set up like this:

```
PubSecKeyOptions keyOptions = new PubSecKeyOptions()
  .setAlgorithm(JWT_HASH_ALGORITHM)
  .setPublicKey(publicKey).setSecretKey(privateKey);
JWTAuthOptions config = new JWTAuthOptions().addPubSecKey(keyOptions);
JWTAuth jwtAuthProvider = JWTAuth.create(vertx, config);
```

And my router like this:

```
router.get("/myresource")
  .handler(JWTAuthHandler.create(jwtAuthProvider).setIssuer(issuer)
  .setAudience(Collections.singletonList(audience)))
  .handler(new MyHandler(userClient));
```

I tried many things so far and read the vert.x documentation for the different auth methods multiple times

- but I failed to find hints on whether I need to wire the mongo auth manually to the JWT auth to use the isAuthorized(role) method.
- If so, my guess would be to write the roles of the users from the mongo db to the authenticated JWTUser which is returned by the `rountingContext.user()` method (i.e. write roles into the JWT token when it's created).

Answer (score 0):

Add `permissionsClaimKey` to `JWTAuthOptions`

```
config.setPermissionsClaimKey("roles");
```

It means that token contains this key

```
"roles": ["prefix_myasd_manager", ...]
```

How add this key to token? In your login method you should check user and get roles. Then

```
ArrayList<String> roles = ...;
JsonObject tokenObject = new JsonObject();
JWTOptions options = new JWTOptions();
options.setPermissions(roles); // or tokenObject.put("roles", new JsonArray(roles));
String tokenEncoded = jwtAuthProvider.generateToken(tokenObject, options);
```